# Custom CNN tuning for detecting vertical vector patterns in an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have NxN images composed from time series data, for each horizontal axis stands for time and vertical axis stand for features.

Order of the features are also attention based, and important. So, order of pixels in each column are very related with the class, and should be handled as "one-column as a whole".

In this context, different vertical slices may be related to different 10 classes, the most frequent class detected among N columns would be the final class of the NxN image.

- What is the correct approach to search Nx1 patterns in this problem?
- Is it possible to classify each column with a DNN-like model and use the output probabilities for each class as an input of another classifier (and how)?
- Or a fine-tuned CNN would work better?

Thanks for any comment.